# Receiving a Struct and Writing to file in socket programming

Tags: c++, c, sockets, struct, tcp

How to receive a struct over tcp socket and output to a file? I have a struct, which is a packet and I'm trying to send this over socket and receive it on the client side and write to the file. I'm using a void pointer as the buffer to store the file data

So far I have

```
struct packet {
    int id;
    void* data;};
```

I'm able to access the id, the int on the client side but when i write the data out to file. the file seems to be corrupted.

UPDATE:

The Server has a file open and will read from the file and make it into a packet and send the packet to the client.

Client will also have a file open for write, as it receives the packets it will write it out to the file.

**Server Side:**

```
current_packet = 0;
While(1)
{
struct packet *current = (packet *)malloc(packet_size+sizeof(int));
current->id = current_packet;
int read = fread(&current->data, 1, packet_size, file);
//end of file
if(read == 0){
break;
}
int byte_write = write(conn, current,read + sizeof(int));
current_packet++;
}
```

**Client Side**

```
current_packet = 0;
While(1)
{
struct packet *current = (packet *)malloc(packet_size+sizeof(int));
int read = read(conn, current, packet_size + sizeof(int));
//end of file
if(read == 0){
break;
}
int byte_write = fwrite(&current->data, 1, read - sizeof(int), file);
fflush(file);
}
```

Comment: How do you manage to know the size of `data` when you receive it at the client site?

Comment: the void pointer data will be assigned  a size in bytes. So the total size of the struct will be size of the data + the size of the int. the client and the server both know the data size. When i write to the client i write the bytes read from file, maximum can be the the set size of data. On the client side i receive the struct then when i fwrite to file, I write the number of bytes read - the size of the int. which will be the size of the data

Comment: So you mean `id` actually contains the size of the file? Are you considering network byte order transmission correctly? You code sample is too narrow to give some concise diagnosis for your problem. Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: id is the sequence number of the packet. The client will open a file to write and receive packets in order and write it out to the file. the void* contains the data. The Server does fread on the file an reads it to the `void * data`. maximum read can be the packet size.

Comment: And `packet_size` is fixed? `void*` needs to point at some allocated memory.

Comment: yes. maximum fread will read is `packet_size` unless its reaching end of the file it will be less than `packet_size`

Comment: And the `void* data;` pointer is set to something like `char buf[packet_size];`? Man, post a minimal code sample as I already mentioned please!

Comment: no i dont set it to anything i just malloc a `struct packet` and fread the file to the `void * data`. I've updated the question with more code

Comment: A `struct packet` doesn't provide any buffer that should be connected to `void* data;` You're writing to unallocated memory, and I have no clue what you're actually doing at the sender side. The only clue I have is: You're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> struct packet *current = (packet *)malloc(packet_size+sizeof(int));
> ```

Supposed `packet_size` is something like

```
 const size_t packet_size = 2048;
```

The code cited above might allocate something big enough to contain a `packet`, but the `data` pointer isn't initialized, and also not considered correctly in the allocation.

What I would do in your case:

Have a fixed size buffer allocated per `packet` like this:

```
struct packet {
    const size_t packet_size = 2048;
    int id;
    std::array<unsigned char,packet_size> data;
};
```